# Create Ubuntu USB-Installer from Debian

Tags: ubuntu, live-usb, system-installation

I have Debian Squeeze and want to create USB flash drive for install Ubuntu 11.04. I've already tried many ways:

1. boot.img.gz + mini.iso at drive's root + syslinux = installer "couldn't found installer iso"
2. boot.img.gz + extract mini.iso to drive's root + syslinux + replace original syslinux.cfg by isolinux.cfg from mini.iso = "invalid keyword in syslinux.cfg" error
3. extract normal CD iso to drive's root + grub = black screen with blinking cursor
4. UnetBootIn from repos + normal CD iso = screen with many vertical color lines

At the moment I'm waiting until usb-creator.exe (launched from Windows) finish.  Could you explain the right way to create Ubuntu USB-installer from Debian?

Comment: Did you verify the ISOs for Ubuntu that you used were fully 100% downloaded and valid by checking the hashes for your downloaded files off of the hashes of the original ISOs (from Ubuntu's site)?

Comment: Yep, md5 sums are equal.

Comment: I was recommended by the Ubuntu people that you theoretically could use `dd` via the command line to get it to work... then all you'd need to do is flag the drive as bootable... but i forget the steps that were outlined... if I can find the instructions, i'll link them here (and thus point you to the correct answer)

Comment: Ooops i lied, that was for an older distro (ancient xD).  According to my research, Ubuntu ISOs are not able to be `dd`'d to a device, and that UNetBootin is the most widely accepted install method, but it seems it didnt work for you.  Did you try unetbootin by downloading it separately (NOT from repos)?

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow.  Just now I've tried to boot qemu from USB created by UnetBootIn:
`qemu /deb/sdd1`
And it says: ''Booting from Hard Disk ... Boot error''.  so the problem is not in the computer to which I am going to install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it like this:

```
$ wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic/main/\
installer-i386/current/images/netboot/boot.img.gz
```

Or to choose current Ubuntu Natty and amd64 architecture:

```
$ wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/\
installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/boot.img.gz

# zcat boot.img.gz > /dev/sdc
# eject /dev/sdc
```

On an old Thinkpad R40 the bios USB boot support was not that great - the bios wanted a mbr, thus I created the USB stick like this:

```
# cfdisk /dev/sdc
only one primary partition
file system type -> 06
bootable
write
# lilo -M /dev/sdc
# zcat boot.img.gz > /dev/sdc1
# eject /dev/sdc
```

Note that this method uses the text-based network installer.

Of course, you have to adjust the USB device name (`/dev/sdc` above), the Distribution name (Karmic is not 11.04) and architecture (x86 vs. amd64).

Comment: I've also tried boot.img.gz.  Is it enough to perform network install?  No additional ISO needed?  And is there a way to use WiFi during this installation or only variant is to use wired connection?

Comment: @Silver_Ghost, yes, it is enough to perform network install. That is the appeal of this method - (plus nowadays network access is often faster than cdrom access). I am not sure about wireless support (never tried it) - using the wire is of course the best supported way - for wireless see e.g. http://geofft.mit.edu/blog/post/109 - but it may get complicated when you want to use WPA, have exotic wireless hardware etc.